# Stored Procedure taking over 10 seconds

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have this stored procedure that is taking over 10 seconds to run. It returns a data set (list of files) to the application. Any suggestions on how to speed it up?

Details about the plan. It looks like query 14 in the plan takes 98% relative to the batch. Inside query 14 is a sort that is 62% of query 14.

I'm using SQL Server 2016. [Estimated query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkE5ggKwW).

Here is the [actual plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyH-wYoDW). Took 5 min. and 21 seconds to run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First insert

The actual plan for the first insert statement reveals some things you should improve:

[image: First insert]

1. I would add an `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to this query. This will allow the optimizer to produce a plan taking into account the runtime values of variables. This should simplify the plan quite a bit.
2. Once the hint above is in place, you should ensure the *Uploads* table has an index with `ClientID, UploadCompleteDttm` as the leading keys. This will provide the required sort order, and allow a seek when `@startdate_local` is not null.
3. The index should also include `FileName, FileUploadID, ProcessErrorText` to avoid lookups. An example index definition would be:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX IndexName
   ON fileManager.FileUploads (ClientID, UploadCompleteDttm)
   INCLUDE (FileName, FileUploadID, ProcessErrorText);
   ```
4. The Clustered Index Scan on *FilesReceived* looks to be very expensive. **Five and a half billion rows** are tested (across multiple scans) to return around 5,000 rows. This cost is well hidden by the residual predicate (as shown in [Sentry One Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer)):

   [image: Scan properties]
5. Add an index to *FilesReceived* keyed on `FileUploadID`. If that index already exists, and the scan persists in the actual execution plan after the previous steps listed here have been applied, use a `FORCESEEK` hint on the *FilesReceived* reference. You may also try `OPTION (USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'));`.

### Second insert

The problematic part that jumps out at me is:

[image: Plan fragment]

This corresponds to the code:

```
(select count(1)
     from fileManager.FilesReceived fr
      join fileManager.Tracking t on fr.FilesReceivedID = t.FilesReceivedID
     where parentfileid = z.FilesReceivedID) as 'HasChildren'
```

The rest of the execution plan is quite large, but does not seem too terrible. I would still try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` again, for the same reasons as for the first query.

If that does not improve performance enough on its own: I would remove the code fragment shown above from the query, persist the result rows (only 5,239 for the example given) in a separate temporary table, then find the `HasChildren` value as a separate step. I would also rewrite the final `INSERT` to use an explicit `TOP (5)` clause instead of using `SET ROWCOUNT 5`.

Ensure the *FilesReceived* table has an index on `ParentFileId`.

Comment: that definitely took care of it. A proc that took over 5 minutes down to 2 seconds.